# Google Drive API returning 404 on upload

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to upload data to a file using the Google Drive v3 API by making a XMLHttpRequest.

I get the id of a file using the File Picker API which returns "0BzAI5S8IJebrUnQtYWFSVzhPdVk", so that the upload URL should be "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/0BzAI5S8IJebrUnQtYWFSVzhPdVk?uploadType=resumable".

After I make the PUT request, it returns a 404 status code with "Not Found" as the responseText.

I've tried it before and it would return with status 200 and I was able to get the Location header from the response, but now I can't get a 200 status code from any file.

Here's my code:

```
// Log the user in using attachClickHandler (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthattachclickhandlercontainer-options--onsuccess-onfailure)

var id = "0BzAI5S8IJebrOFVMTU5Od183Q2M";
var access_token = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('PUT', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' + id + '?uploadType=resumable');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) console.log(this.status);
};
xhr.send();
```

No matter which file I choose, it always outputs 404 as the status code. I follow what it says at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload, but it mentions nothing of why you would receive a 404 response. Any help?

Comment: From the page you link, you are missing a couple of mandatory http headers. Otherwise, 404 would suggest there is a problem with the file ID you are using. Are you sure it's correct and is writeable by the logged in user?

Comment: They're definitely writable. I've tried with three different files on my own account that I own, so I can write to all three. Which other headers am I missing? The X-Content-Upload-Length/Type headers are optional and the Content-Type header is required only if I send metadata.

Comment: The other was content-length. Not sure if it's the problem, just ruling out all possibilities. Try another operation on the ID such as a files.get, just to double check the ID.

Comment: File.get returns a 200 response with the proper information. It also works on the API Explorer on https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get so it can't be the ID.

Comment: Also the browser doesn't let me change the Content-Length header. The browser sets the header automatically and throws an error if I try to change it manually: Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"

Comment: I do like a challenge :-)    What scopes did you authorize?

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

Comment: I spotted this "Restart uploads if a 404 Not Found error is received after attempting to resume or upload a chunk. This indicates the upload session has expired and must be restarted from the beginning. Upload sessions expire after 1 week of inactivity." So it could be that Drive is interpreting your PUT as a continuation, rather than a new request. Try setting the "optional" headers. If that fails, try including an empty metadata object in the body.

Comment: Ive tried both those. Still got a 404. I think the 404 error you mentioned is pertaining to the URL you get back from the original upload request (in the Location response header). I'm getting a 404 from the initial request itself

Comment: you're right it is, or rather it should be. Somehow Drive is interpreting your PUT as a continuation, not the initial request.

Comment: So is there something I could try to get it working? Also, the first time I tried it yesterday, it worked. Shouldn't I still have 6 days before it would expire?

Comment: have you tried including an empty meta data object in the PUT body?

Comment: Yup. I put "{}" with Content-Type set to "application/json; charset=UTF-8". Still 404

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to do the wrong thing. I wanted to *update* a file, not *upload* one. Instead of using `"PUT"`, I should've been using `"PATCH"` as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update). This returned a 200 response with the `Location` header to make the actual change.

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER! **THE DOCUMENTATION IS WRONG!** The documentation in the [Resumable Uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload) section says to use PUT, not PATCH. [Here is a screenshot.](https://i.imgur.com/QfSbwSh.png) I have been banging my head against this for days, going over and over it.

Comment: I have sent a feedback to Google using their feedback tool to fix the documentation. I hope they will fix it soon :)

Comment: Good catch! 2020 is knocking the door and the documentation is still wrong.